# How to save neuron training data?

Tags: c#, neural-network

I wrote a neuron that learns to convert values. But I want it to save the learning result. How to do it?

Here is the neuron source code:

```
public class Neuron
        {
            private decimal weight = 0.5m;
            public decimal Errors { get; private set; }
            public decimal Smooth { get; set; } = 0.0000001m;
            public decimal InputData(decimal input)
            {
                return input * weight;
            }
            public decimal RestoreInputData(decimal output)
            {
                return output / weight;
            }
            public void Training(decimal input, decimal expResult)
            {
                var mainResult = input * weight;
                Errors = expResult - mainResult;
                var correction = (Errors / mainResult) * Smooth;
                weight += correction;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal uk = 100;
            decimal eu = 3.34m;

            Neuron neuron = new Neuron();

            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                i++;
                neuron.Training(uk, eu);
                if (i % 700000 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Iteration: {i}\tIssue:\t{neuron.Errors}");
                }
            } while (neuron.Errors > neuron.Smooth || neuron.Errors < -neuron.Smooth);

            Console.WriteLine("Training the end!");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your value: ");
        decimal res = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine($"{neuron.InputData(res)}");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I created this neuron from an example on the Internet to understand how it works.

Comment: You can serialize the "neuron" instance and store it wherever you like. Next time just deserialize it and use it.

Comment: And how can you do this in more detail?